# App crash after removing firebase child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

My app shows in a `RecyclerView` some various firebase children and its Values.
I made a method on the app, which can delete a children but right after I removed one of the firebase children which is displayed on the RecyclerView on a Fragment before my app crashes because it cannot found the childrens name and Values on the RecyclerView anymore (Obvious, because I just removed them)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at world.cryneo.partytime.java.RequestsFragment$2$1.onDataChange(RequestsFragment.java:108)
```

Here it doesnt get the childrens Values because the children is deleted.

```
final String eventName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
```

In the block `onCreateView` i told the database to keep syncroned. I thought this would fix it but the problem is still here.

```
mEventsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
```

So how can I tell the firebase and Recycler View that I just deleted one children and its Values and it should not crash by downloading the non-existant datas?

Here is the way i get the children from the firebase:

```
 mEventsDatabase.child(list_event_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        final String eventName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just checking if the snapshot exists?

```
mEventsDatabase.child(list_event_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // ADD THIS
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                          return;
                        }


                        final String eventName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
```